# Giving a user access to the webcam

Tags: debian, security, camera, polkit, consolekit

I have a user that I use to run untrusted programs (more specifically, Skype). I would like to give that user access to the webcam.

I am using Debian, where the standard way to do this is to put users in the `video` group. However, it seems like this allows them to do more than just access the webcam, more specifically they can "write to video memory" https://www.debian-administration.org/article/109/How_Debian_controls_hardware_access. I am not sure about the security implications of this.

What is the proper way to give a user access specifically to the webcam? I could change the ownership of `/dev/video0` to a specific group that I would put the restricted user and my regular user in, but is this the correct way, and is there a proper way to make it persist across reboots? Alternatively, I have heard that this was doable with PolicyKit or ConsoleKit, but I have been unable to find examples online. How can this be done then?

To give more details: the unprivileged user will never use a TTY or a GDM to log in. It runs its applications using sudo launched by my regular user, and accesses my regular user's pulseaudio daemon and my regular user's X server (via xpra).

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!